# What kind of connector to snowflake that automaticly uploads new data would you use for IoT data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am just starting to set up a project to keep track of some open, home devices that are enabled for an at home network. I have a program that saves this data, and am putting together a process to upload that data to Snowflake automatically. I would like to know what you would recommend so I can easily access the home device information from anywhere.

The two options I am considering are aws's and snowflake's auto ingest option using the snowpipe rest api, which I have tested with only a few devices.

I am considering these two factors - which method can I set up to upload and select data quickly from a mobile app written in python or ruby depending on the device.

Any advice or resources you can point me to on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a pretty open question, so details from you might make this answer a bit more detailed, as well.  However, in general, I would suggest that if your IoT data can be stored directly to Blob Storage (S3 in the case of AWS), then you should leverage Snowflake's Snowpipe for continuous ingestion.  Also, look into Tasks and Streams to automate moving that data through whatever processes you'll setup once the data is in Snowflake.

A good reference for you:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-pipelines-intro.html